# Why lists in the list are not converted into a row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of lists, and each inner list have 7 elements. I want to construct a dataframe, but I found it always not right.

Code are as bellow:

```
lines=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
headers = ['sales', 'price', 'name', 'res', 'url', 'platform', 'discount']
df=pd.DataFrame(lines,columns=headers)
```

what is wrong with the code? My pandas is 0.19.2 version. And I am running it with pycharm.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think there is not wrong with your code. Why do you think so?

Comment: It works as expected here on same version of pandas. No issues.

Comment: Could you please define what would be `"right"`?

Comment: Sorry I asked a really silly question. This code is right, sorry for that.